# ¿Como usar un solo controlador para generar mis urls genéricas?

Tags: c#, controller, seo

Tengo una tabla con la que quiero hacer un catalogo.

mi tabla esta asi:

```
Id    Producto    Descripcion    Precio
```

voy a realizar un index donde liste todos los productos con su nombre y me enlacen con un link a una vista donde tenga su descripcion, **yo se como hacer todo lo anterior**, pero no se como hacer para que cada enlace del index se reciba automaticamente o genericamente el controlador por ejemplo al poner **/product/id/aqui-cualquier-cade** por ejemplo solo quiero usar el controlador producto y el id después del **id/** la cadena no me importa solo es estadístico

```
<a href="https://mydomain.com/product/id/name-of-product">name of product</a>
```

yo no creo que tenga que crear un controlador name-of-product y otro other-name-of-product me imagino que hay algo generico donde yo envio al *controlador* **product** *accion* **index**

ejemplo: **ProductController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MySite.Controllers
{
    public class ProductyController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Product
        public ActionResult Index(int id, string productstring)
        {
            return Content(productstring + "example fooo bar ..");
            // or
            return View("my_generic_view_styled_css.cshtml");
        }
    }
}
```

para que al poner https://mydomain.com/product/id/foo-bar-any

me regrese mi **index.cshtml** con mi info yo se como rellenarla pero lo que no se como hacerlo con las urls para lo del SEO

Mi problema es que las urls me dan 404

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! a ver si entiendo, esto no es un problema de codigo, si no de seo?

Comment: código quiero saber de un controlador que reciba mi url `/id/aqui-cualquier-cosa-no-importa`  tome mi id y con eso yo puedo jugar, gracias

Comment: El scaffold basico de c# mvc te arma el controller exactamente como vos queres en el ejemplo

Comment: me sigue dando un 404

Comment: ¿Quieres ponerle `[Route("{id}/{productstring}")]` a la Action? Para empezar, si tu controlador se llama `ProductyController` (Sin saber tu tabla de rutas actuales), la URL actual debe ser: `localhost:<puerto>/Producty/{id}`, si agregas el atributo que menciono arriba, puede que sea: `localhost:<puerto>/Producty/{id}/{productstring}`.

Comment: `[Route("{id}/{productstring}")]
public class ProductyController : Controller`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final logre solucionar mi pregunta todo el truco estaba en **RouteConfig.cs**

Agregue lo siguiente:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Product", 
    url: "product/{id}/{company}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", id = "", product = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Otro truco lo hizo lo siguien y fue lo mas importante:

Agregar

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); //super important for solution
```

Justo despues de:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

Todo en **RouteConfig.cs**

Answer (score 2):

Lo que quieres hacer es obtener un Detalle de cada uno de tus productos, para eso debes realizar un método ActionResult (Una acción del controlador) que devuelva en respuesta el detalle de ese producto.

Primero de todo hay que identificar la `KEY` del Producto, en tu caso va a ser el `Id`, nuestro método debe recibir como parámetro este Id.

Como sólo será la visualización de los detalles del producto será un método `[HttpGet]` ya que no tiene que procesar ni enviar a la Base de datos ningún archivo. Sólo obtener datos de ella.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Details(int Id)
{
            var producto = data.ProductosRepository.Find(Id);
            if (producto == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(producto);
}
```

Ahora lo que debes hacer es Crear la vista de esta nueva acción del Controlador, segundo click sobre el nuevo Action Result y Agregar Vista, 
para visualizar los datos de tu producto debes enviarle como modelo tu repositorio **Producto**, es decir:

```
@model data.Productos
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}
<h2>
    Detalles
</h2>
<fieldset>
        <legend>Cargador</legend>
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Producto)</dt>
            <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Producto)</dd>
            <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descripcion)</dt>
            <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Descripcion)</dd>
            <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Precio)</dt>
            <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Precio)</dd>
        </dl>
    <p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Volver a la lista", "Index")
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Espero haberte dado una mano.

Un saludo!

Comment: muy bien pero eso no es mi problema el problema es que al escribir la url en la barra de navegacion me da 404 en la url de producto **/product/id/aqui-cualquier-cadena** como recibo con el controlador product el id, después del id/ la cadena no me importa

Comment: @laur Justamente, tu problema está en que /product/id/aqui-cualquier-cadena no tiene una vista creada, que sería tu Details del Producto. Cada método de tu controlador tienen una Vista personalizada, ya sea Index/Edit/Create/Details o la que tu quieras.

Comment: si el problema que no me toma los valores y no quiero hacer `/product?id=12&product=blablabla` como vez en mi código tengo como un ejemplo `return View("my_generic_view_styled_css.cshtml");` o `return View("details.cshtml");`

Comment: Hay que especificar la routa del controlador con [Route("/product/id")], el nombre del producto es un sinsentido porque ya se sabe por el id.

Comment: [Route("/id/product")] o asi  [Route("/{id}/{product}")] ?

Answer (score 0):

se puede definir en tu Global.asax o donde tengas definido el mapa de rutas, un routing especial de la siguiente forma

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "ProductDetails",
        "product/{productId}/{productName}", // URL
        new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", productName = UrlParameter.Optional }, // URL Defaults
        new { id = @"\d+" } // URL Constraints
    );
```